# некорректно отображается margin-top в процентах

Tags: html, css, вёрстка

Проценты выставлены правильно, но `.mycompany` не там где должен быть по макету. От верхнего края он обязан находится на отдалении в 59px, вся высота `.mycompany` составляет 790px. Но! при использовании `top` всё работает правильно

CSS

```
* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
.general {
    height: 6200px;
}
header {
    height: 790px;
    background-color: black;
}
.mycompany {
    position: relative;
    margin-left: 12.1%;
    margin-top: 7.2%;
    color: white;
    font-size: 1.5em;
    display: inline-block;
    text-transform: uppercase;
}
```

HTML

```
<div class="general">

    <header>
        <span class="mycompany">mycompany</span>
    </header>

</div>
```

Comment: Он считается от ширины, а не от высоты родителя - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34706180/how-is-the-margin-top-percentage-calculated

Comment: проблема была в том, что margin-top считался от ширины родителя, а мне казалось что это считается от высоты. Но сейчас уже все исправлено

Comment: и как делать адаптивную верстку без них?

Comment: предлагаете ли вы использовать медиа запросы?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Он считается от ширины, а не от высоты родителя https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34706180/how-is-the-margin-top-percentage-calculated

Теперь только остается вопрос, как высчитать высоту относительно ширины